# change li class if page is active

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In rails I want to change my class of the li element if the page is active. I made an application helper but the code does not work. If I place the code outside of the element it does work. (say within p tags)

My application helper file looks like this:

```
  def activepage(path)
    ' class="active"' if current_page?(path)
  end
```

And this is how the sidebar partial looks:

```
    <li<%= activepage(root_path) %>>
        <a href="blank-page.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-file"></i> Blank Page</a>
    </li>
```

It looks like the li does not get created if I load the page. Any idea why and what is the most elegant way to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: If `<li>` doesn't even get into the resulting view, the problem is outside it.

Comment: Any idea why I'm here by tag jQuery?

Comment: Maybe I can solve it using jquery? if not I'll delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging the problem by changing your view code to:

```
<li <%= current_page?(root_path) ? "class=active" : "class=not-active" %>>
    <a href="blank-page.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-file"></i> Blank Page</a>
</li>
```

If `current_page?(root_path)` is true then the li class will be active, if `current_page?(root_path)` is false then the class will be not-active.

If `current_page?(root_path)` is returning false then that is your problem, `class="active"` will never get added.

Answer (score 0):

< li "<%= activepage(root_path) %>" >

Please put the ruby code it inside inverted commas.
Also make sure that the helper method is returning value as expected.

Also try looking at the html code generated, using firebug or inspecting it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by putting the helper within class="helper".

```
<li class="<%= activepage(root_path) %>">
```